# What's the relation between Euclidean and Minkowski entities in lattice field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wick-rotation, lattice-gauge-theory

To my understanding, lattice QFT basically continues the time $t$ (and fields depend on it) in Minkowski space action to imaginary time $\tau\equiv it$. But normally when we do calculations in lattice QFT, we consider a real $\tau$. So does this real $\tau$ reflects the physics of the actual Minkowski spacetime? Or do we need to consider an imaginary $\tau$ for that?

Comment: I imagine you know this, but we don't evolve in imaginary time and regard the result as the same as evolution in real time. Instead quantities are calculated in imaginary time which themselves can be Wick rotated back to real time, such as correlators.

Answer (score 1):

Real $\tau$ does not reflect all of the physics of Minkowski spacetime. But there are many physical observables that do not depend on the choice of signature. For instance, if you measure a two-point correlation function at long times in the Euclidean, you get an exponential decay
$$G(\tau_1,\tau_2) \sim e^{-m|\tau_1 - \tau_2|}$$
where $m$ is the physical (renormalized) mass of the lightest exchanged particle. In Minkowski, you would perhaps have measured this $m$ by performing a scattering experiment:
$$A(s,t) \sim \frac{p(t)}{s - m^2} + \ldots$$
where $p(t)$ is a polynomial that depends on the spin of the particle. It would be extremely complicated (if not impossible) to measure such a scattering amplitude directly in the Euclidean. Likewise, there are some intrinsically Euclidean observables (like the thermal partition function).

As a matter of principle, if you know all Euclidean correlators you can analytically continue them to get their real-time counterparts, and vice versa. But in lattice simulations you can only measure correlators up to a finite resolution. So in practice you extract physical observables directly on the lattice, without performing any analytic continuation.